# WordPress Theme Import Slider Error

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming, themes

I`m trying to import a slider for a theme that I chose in WordPress.

But, when I select the .zip file, I received the following error:

This page isn’t working. localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Thanks

Comment: Check your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Its a syntax error in your functions file, try to check it in : **wp-content/themes/your_theme/functions.php**

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nabil. And which part exactly should I change or check in the functions.php file?

Comment: The error could be anywhere, not just in `functions.php`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: What's the opening syntax in your function ?